# I can't use JS to auto-fill `select` elements on a form built in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, google-chrome-extension

I'm auto-filling a form using a Chrome extension. The form is built in react and I can successfully update `input` and `textarea`s, but while I'm able to change the value of `select` elements, it doesn't save properly and reverts.

```
reactSetValue(document.getElementById("Dropdown 1"), 1, "select"); //DOES NOT WORK
reactSetValue(document.getElementById("Textarea 1"), "testing testing 123", "textarea") //Works fine
reactSetValue(document.getElementById("Input 1"), "Title text", "input"); //Also works fine

function reactSetValue(i,v,t = "select"){
    var nativeInputValueSetter = null;
    if(t=="input") nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set;
    if(t=="select") nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLSelectElement.prototype, "value").set;
    if(t=="textarea") nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype, "value").set;
    nativeInputValueSetter.call(i, v);

    var ev2 = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
    i.dispatchEvent(ev2);
}
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong with select fields but I don't know enough about React to work out what. Any tips would be appreciated! Perhaps an event other than "input" is needed to make the selection?

Comment: It is a really, really, really bad idea to directly manipulate the DOM when using React.  React itself is "in charge of" the DOM and likely isn't recognizing some of the changes you are making to the DOM, so when React goes to do submits or whatever, it likely isn't picking up your changes (remember, React also maintains its own "virtual DOM", so your changes are bypassing that entire mechanism).

Comment: @GregFenton This form validates on field changes so inputs and textareas are definitely being successfully changed with this system. And correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like this code isn't editing the DOM, it's sending an event to React to make the change using nativeInputValueSetter? Is there a different way I should be doing this, to talk to React directly?

Comment: Use `change` event for selects.

Comment: @wOxxOm this worked, thank you!